# Objective C syntax understanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I am a newbie to objective C. I was looking through a few tutorials online to create like a dropdown using the iOS sdk. So I came across the picker view, and from a few online resources I came to know that I would have to provide a delegate and a datasource for the picker.

And the syntax in the header file for the interface is something like this.

```
@interface ViewController : UIController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@end
```

Now, I understand that UIController is the parent of ViewController, but what does the greater than & less than mean here?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `UIViewController`? There is no `UIController` class in Cocoa. If this is your own class, don't use the `UI` prefix.

Comment: By the way, UIController should probably be UIViewController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>` means that the class *conforms to* these two *protocols*. Protocols are akin to interfaces in C# and Java<sup>✝</sup>; they describe a list of methods you must implement in your class. Your class, `ViewController`, must implement all methods that are required by the `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocols.

See [*Working with Protocols*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html), [*UIPickerViewDataSource Protocol Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [*UIPickerViewDelegate Protocol Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html).

<sup>✝ With the slight difference that methods in protocols can be marked as optional, whereas methods in interfaces are always required.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Those are called protocols: formal lists of declarations for which the corresponding methods and/or properties are to be implemented by the class that **conforms to these protocols.**

[More about protocols here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)